# Message format/specification for distributed REST services?

Tags: rest, message-queue, microservices, message

I have a growing number of REST services that talk to each other with JSON. Right now, the communication is direct, but it's possible that a broker might process and distribute later on.

This is the only one I've found so far:
https://github.com/cjus/umf/blob/master/umf.md

Are there others that would be better suited? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't seen other universal formats, so I have nothing to compare UMF to, but one of the glaring problems I can see is that there is no schema defined for the message, beyond the markdown page in Git. Without a schema how would one validate a message based on UMF is actually valid UMF?

Comment: I have added an issue to the project https://github.com/cjus/umf/issues/3

Comment: thanks, appreciate you opening that issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/).
There is more explanatory info [available](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/) also.